# How to fill NAs with median of means of 2-column groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, nan, fillna

Working with pandas, I have a dataframe with two hierarchies `A` and `B`, where B can be `NaN`, and I want to fill some NaNs in `D` in a particular way:

In the example below, A has "B-subgroups" where there are no values at all for D (e.g. `(1, 1)`), while A also has values for D in other subgroups (e.g. `(1, 3)`).

Now I want to get the `mean` of each subgroup (`120, 90 and 75` for `A==1`), find the `median` of these means (`90` for `A==1`) and use this median to fill NaNs in the other subgroups of `A==1`.

Groups like `A==2`, where there are only NaNs for D, should not be filled.

Groups like `A==3`, where there are some values for D but only rows with B being NaN have NaN in D, should not be filled if possible (I intend to fill these later with the mean of all values of D of their whole A groups).

Example df:

```
d = {'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    'B': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
    'D': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 120, 120, 90, 75, np.NaN, np.NaN, 60, 50, np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
A       B       D
1       1       NaN
1       2       NaN
1       3       120
1       3       120
1       4       90
1       5       75
1       6       NaN
2       1       NaN
3       1       60
3       NaN     50
3       NaN     NaN
```

Expected result:

```
A       B       D
1       1       90
1       2       90
1       3       120
1       3       120
1       4       90
1       5       75
1       6       90
2       1       NaN
3       1       60
3       NaN     50
3       NaN     NaN
```

With `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].mean().groupby(['A']).agg('median')` or `.median()` I seem to get the right values, but using

```
df['D'] = df['D'].fillna(
    df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].mean().groupby(['A']).agg('median')
)
```

does not seem to change any values in D.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while and cannot find any solution anywhere.

Comment: Can you please code to generate your example DataFrame so people can just copy paste it in a console and work with?

Comment: Just did, even though my question has been answered in the meantime. Sorry that I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is correct. After that we use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map) to map the correct medians to each group in column `A`.

Finally we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally fill in column `D` if `B is not NaN`:

```
medians = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].mean().groupby(['A']).agg('median')
df['D'] = np.where(df['B'].notna(),                        # if B is not NaN
                   df['D'].fillna(df['A'].map(medians)),   # fill in the median
                   df['D'])                                # else keep the value of column D
```

```
    A    B      D
0   1 1.00  90.00
1   1 2.00  90.00
2   1 3.00 120.00
3   1 3.00 120.00
4   1 4.00  90.00
5   1 5.00  75.00
6   1 6.00  90.00
7   2 1.00    nan
8   3 1.00  60.00
9   3  nan  50.00
10  3  nan    nan
```

Comment: That seems to have done the job, thank you very much!